# how to extract the wiki code instead of html from a page on wikipedia in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, wikipedia-api

Any ideas how to download the wiki code that shows up on a Wikipedia page when you click "edit" on one of the Wikipedia pages?  Example:

```
//EXAMPLE:

using System.Net;

public void download() {
    string page = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Albatross&action=edit";

    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        string htmlCode = client.DownloadString(page);
        // how to get the wiki code in the html edit box here?
}
```

Comment: it appears to be within a textarea, so find the textarea in your response and then get the content within it

Comment: Use action=raw, see [How to download the wikicode of a Wikipedia page?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/73076/how-to-download-the-wikicode-of-a-wikipedia-page)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is your concrete problem? Have you inspected the response?

Answer (score 1):

**Update without HAP**
As per wimh's comment. Simply appending `&action=raw` as a query string lets you do the job without scraping.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;

public class Program
{
    private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    public static void Main()
    {
        var response = client.GetAsync("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Albatross&action=edit&action=raw").Result;
        var rawEditCode = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        Console.WriteLine(rawEditCode);
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NwZC3I

**Original Answer**
You could use [HtmlAgilitypack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) and simply scrape it:

```
using System;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument html = web.Load("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Albatross&action=edit");

        var editorContent = html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(@"//textarea[@id='wpTextbox1']").InnerHtml;
        Console.WriteLine(editorContent);
    }
}
```

dotNetFiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fmsT1m

Answer (score 0):

```
   string[] GetWikiCode(string topic)
    {
        string htmlCode = "";
        string url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=" 
            + topic + "&action=raw";
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Downloading: {0}", url));
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            htmlCode = client.DownloadString(url);
        }
        string[] delimit = new string[] { "\n", "\r\n" };
        string[] result = htmlCode.Split(delimit,
                              StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        return result;
    }
```